Decorating productController in prestashop 8.1.6
I am trying to decorate the productController in prestashop 8.1.6 but I am getting below error:
**You have requested a non-existent service "PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\Sell\Catalog\Product\ProductController".
**

Is there something I'm overlooking? I'm happy to provide more details if that would be helpful.
Thanks.
